# Is it possible to configure VS2008 to single step the heading of a for as if it were one step?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, for-loop, trace

When single stepping into a for loop such as:

```
for (int = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

The debugger goes thru each part of the for "header" individually thus requiring 4 keypresses to step each loop iteration.

Is it possible to instruct the debugger to consider the `"for (int i = 1 ... etc"` as one step instead of 3 ?  thus requiring only two keypresses per loop iteration ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Put a break point after the for loop... and on the first line within it... then it's just one key press (run)? :)

Comment: @forsvarir: thank you.  That answers my question.  Essentially, the debugger cannot be "told" to consider the for header as if it were a single instruction but the effect can be "simulated" by using breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possibile because the operations performed in the loop header are different instructions.
The easier way is to put a breakpoint at the beginning of your loop and jump there with F5 (start debug).

Answer (score 1):

You can put conditional break points. Like break only when value of i equal to 3.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a breakpoint on the opening brace?  You can then just hit F5 to step into each iteration.